# How to check in perl if path is a sub directory or a file from a list of base paths (who have globed paths)

Tags: regex, perl, shell, path, glob

I need an optimum way to match a path with huge list of probable basepaths (which may be many directory levels up). The base paths themselves may be valid shell globbed paths

E.g.

I need to match the path **/a/b-12/c/d/e/fg/hi/94.txt** in the list below:

1. /a/b-*/e
2. /x/y*
3. /x/{a,b,s*}e
4. /a/{a,b*,c}2/c/d
5. /a/b*/c/e
6. ...

The list is long with 10Ks of such paths. Once we have identified the probable parent paths I can verify them by chdir/cd to the path etc.

I wish to a regex match on the list but shell globbed paths are difficult for me to match. Are there Perl modules which can help me in this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to try `Text::Glob` from CPAN.
you dont have to use `glob_to_regex`, I was just playing with it, but this matches:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Glob qw(glob_to_regex);

my @arr = ('/a/b-12/c/d/e/fg/hi/94.txt');

my $regex = glob_to_regex('/a/{a,b*,c}2/c/d/e/fg/hi/94.txt');
print "REGEX: $regex\n";
if ($arr[0] =~ m/$regex/) {
  print "Matches\n";
}
```

Comment: `/a/{a,b*,c}2/c/d` should be the glob pattern